# Как получить все переменные вида {{name}} для шаблона из docx файла?

Tags: python, jinja2, docx

Есть файл docx с текстом

"
Так говорила в июле {{ data }} года известная {{name1}}, фрейлина и приближенная императрицы {{name2}}, встречая важного и чиновного князя Василия, первого приехавшего на ее вечер. {{name1}} кашляла несколько дней, у нее был грипп, как она говорила
"

Как получить список переменных ['data', 'name1', 'name2']
Используется библиотека docx

Comment: Из просто текста - `set(re.findall(r"\{{2}\s*([^}]+)\s*\}{2}", text))`.

Comment: @GrAnd это не совсем подходит, так как в шаблоне встречаются также и {{endfor}}, которые мне не нужны, есть ли решение с помощью библиотеки jinja2 или docx.